# arrayList appears to only be created if one activity is done first, not the other

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I'm having an issue with this app I'm writing for a class in school.  It's a basic workout tracking app.

I have an arrayList but the Cardio.java activity can only save to the arrayList if Strength.java has already saved something first.  Not sure why as the code is the same for both.

I've double checked that the code is the same for both activities so not sure why it only seems to save to the arrayList if strenght.java does first.  Then it works fine.

### Cardio.java

```
public class Cardio extends AppCompatActivity {

    String cardio;
    String miles;
    String time;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cardio);

        Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseHelper dbUtil = new DatabaseHelper();

                Spinner cardioSpinner = findViewById(R.id.listCardioType);
                cardio = cardioSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                EditText milesText = findViewById(R.id.txtMileageInput);
                miles = milesText.getText().toString();
                EditText timeText = findViewById(R.id.txtTimeInput);
                time = timeText.getText().toString();

                String record = cardio + ": " + miles + " miles, " + time + " mins.";

                Log.d("test", record);

                ArrayList strengthWorkouts = dbUtil.getArrayList("strength_workouts");
                Log.d("test", strengthWorkouts.toString());
                strengthWorkouts.add(record);
                dbUtil.saveArrayList(strengthWorkouts, "strength_workouts");

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Cardio.this, "Workout Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(0, 0, -200);
                toast.show();
            }


        });

        Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "I just completed a workout! " + cardio + ": " + miles + " miles, " + time + " mins.";
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareBody);
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share Using:"));

            }
        });

    }
}
```

---

### Strength.java

```
public class Strength extends AppCompatActivity {

    String exercise;
    String repCount;
    String weight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_strength);

        Button saveButton = findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseHelper dbUtil = new DatabaseHelper();

                Spinner exerciseSpinner = findViewById(R.id.listWeightType);
                exercise = exerciseSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                EditText repCountText = findViewById(R.id.txtRepInput);
                repCount = repCountText.getText().toString();
                EditText weightText = findViewById(R.id.txtWeightInput);
                weight = weightText.getText().toString();

                String record = exercise + ": " + repCount + " reps, " + weight + " lbs.";

                Log.d("test", record);

                ArrayList strengthWorkouts = dbUtil.getArrayList("strength_workouts");
                Log.d("test", strengthWorkouts.toString());
                strengthWorkouts.add(record);
                dbUtil.saveArrayList(strengthWorkouts, "strength_workouts");

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Strength.this, "Workout Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(0, 0, -200);
                toast.show();

            }
        });

        Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "I just completed a workout! " + exercise + ": " + repCount + " reps, " + weight + " lbs.";
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareBody);
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share Using:"));

            }
        });


    }
}
```

---

### History.java

```
public class History extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "ListDataActivity";

    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        DatabaseHelper dbUtils = new DatabaseHelper();
        ArrayList<String> strengthHistory = dbUtils.getArrayList("strength_workouts");


        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                strengthHistory );

        mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript and Java are two completely separate languages.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `dbUtils.getArrayList("strength_workouts")` return a null ArrayList if you don't have data in your database for "strength_workouts".

Try to create the list if it's null in your activity:

```
ArrayList strengthWorkouts = dbUtil.getArrayList("strength_workouts");

if(strengthHistory == null) {
   strengthHistory = new ArrayList<String>();
}

strengthWorkouts.add(record);
dbUtil.saveArrayList(strengthWorkouts, "strength_workouts");
```